# Level curves of $f(r) = \sum_{i=1}^na_id(r,r_i)$ with $r_i\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: metric-spaces, conic-sections

Let $$f(r) = \sum_{i=1}^na_id(r,r_i)$$
Where each $r_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and each $a_i\in \mathbb{R}$
and $d:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ denotes the usual distance function. That is, $f$ is a linear function of the distance from $n$ points in $n$-dimensional space. What are the level surfaces (curves) of $f$?  When $n=2$, I believe these are conic sections (please correct me if I'm wrong about this). Are there analogs for $n>2$? If this cannot be answered in full generality, (which I'm guessing it can't) what area of math deals with such questions?

Comment: They are ellipses when $n=2$ and the coefficients are equal. Interesting question. Do you need the answer for some purpose ([edit] to tell us if so) or are you just curious.

Comment: @EthanBolker I was just curious.

Comment: The title and body of your question contradict one another. The former uses the square of the distance, the latter the distance. I think the latter is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I've deleted the one in the title.

Answer (score 1):

Information about the two dimensional case.

Let $A$ and $B$ be points in the plane and suppose $a+b = 1$. Define
$$
f(X) = a \cdot d(X,A) + b \cdot d(X,B).
$$
Then the level curves of $f$ are convex ovals surrounding $A$ and $B$. They are described by fourth degree equations in the coordinates that result when you start by squaring both sides of
$$
c - a \cdot d(X,A) = b \cdot d(X,B).
$$
That will leave a square root on the left. Move all the other terms on the left to the right and square again to see the fourth degree expression. It's not pretty.

[image]

When $a = b = 1/2$ the level curves are ellipses with foci $A$ and $B$: the third and fourth order terms cancel.

When $a=1, b=0$ the level curves are circles centered at $A$.

When $c$ is very large $A$ and $B$ are close together relative to $c$. The level curve looks more like a circle.